# show data with no Filter in power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax

So, this is my query , sorry would not be able to provide my data

let's imagine there is a table called sales it has 4 columns (seller , quantiy, price, total price)

now i have few sellers whose price are yet to update in SQL but i have their Quantity how much they have sold. i have created dax query for total price which is simple sumx(quantity * price).

now here is my issue when i filter the table sales by a seller whose price isn't available in SQL it shows a blank table something like this

[image]

I at least want to show the shipped quantity if there is no price for that seller.

(P.s. Show items with no data isn't providing desirable results)

Comment: this might be bcus of your relationship settings between the tables. could be useful if you provide more context on this. also sample/dummy data is highly appreciated for test cases

Comment: You need to provide "sample" data so that your question is properly understood. You don't need to provide actual data - just a sample that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Okay will provide sample data , :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use the time-honored trick of adding 0 to the column/measure that is showing blank.

```
SellingPrice = SUM (SellingPrice) + 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Please test this.

Please keep in mind that It is a table function (ADDMISSINGITEMS); so create a new table and paste the code below to see the result set.

(Table Function - You need to create a new table before pasting the below code:)

```
Show_Missing_Data =
ADDMISSINGITEMS (
    'FactTable'[sku],
    'FactTable'[shippedQty],
    SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
        'FactTable'[sku],
        'FactTable'[shippedQty],
        "Total Sales", CALCULATE ( SUMX ( 'FactTable', [quantity] * [price] ) )
    ),
    'FactTable'[sku],
    'FactTable'[shippedQty]
)
```

If you want **a measure** to slice & dice in a table:

```
Total_Sales =
VAR AllSales =
    CALCULATE ( SUMX ( 'FactTable', [quantity] * [price] ) )
VAR Show_Missing_Data =
    ADDMISSINGITEMS (
        'FactTable'[sku],
        'FactTable'[shippedQty],
        SUMMARIZECOLUMNS (
            'FactTable'[sku],
            'FactTable'[shippedQty],
            "Total Sales", CALCULATE ( SUMX ( 'FactTable', [quantity] * [price] ) )
        ),
        'FactTable'[sku],
        'FactTable'[shippedQty]
    )
VAR Result =
    CALCULATE ( AllSales, Show_Missing_Data )
RETURN
    Result
```

Comment: it shows "The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value." 
i created a new table and created a measure and pasted the code

Answer (score 0):

```
SUMX(
    table
    ,quantity * if(
                   ISBLANK(price)
                   ,1
                   ,price
                )
)
```